# How to prevent looping on specific objects found in json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a table with json data obtained in an ajax response. I get an array of objects that looks like this:

**JSON Array of Objects**

```
[  
   {  
      "ItemCount":2
   },
   {  
      "ProductID":"4220068",
      "ProdMfg":"",
      "Desc":"Cambridge&#32;AR&#32;Charcoal&#32;Grey",
      "Quantity":1,
      "UnitPrice":"$1.00",
      "ExtPrice":"$1.00"
   },
   {  
      "ProductID":"4220002",
      "ProdMfg":"",
      "Desc":"Cambridge&#32;AR&#32;Dual&#32;Black",
      "Quantity":1,
      "UnitPrice":"$1.00",
      "ExtPrice":"$1.00"
   },
   {  
      "ItemTotExtPrice":2
   }
]
```

**JQuery Code**

```
function getPallet() {
    var minipallet = $('#mini-pallet');
    var minipalletmsgnoitems = $('#msg-noitems');
    var minipallettable = $('#mini-pallet-table');
    var minipallettablelines = $("#mini-pallet-table .mini-pallet-lines");
    var spinner = $('.loadingSpinner');
    var spinnerMed = $('.loadingSpinner-med');
    var spinnerBig = $('.loadingSpinner-big');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: 'WebCatPageServer.exe?aShoppingCart',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            minipalletmsgnoitems.add(minipallet).hide();
            spinner.show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            spinner.hide();
            if (data[0].ItemCount === 0) {
                minipallettable.hide();
                minipalletmsgnoitems.html('<div class="col-xs-12 alert alert-danger"><img class="alert-icon" src="wp-content/themes/roofmart/assets/icons/svg/alert-placeholder-iconRed.svg" alt="No Items in Pallet Icon"/><p class="med"><b>You have no items in your pallet.</b></p></div>').show();
            } else {
                minipalletmsgnoitems.hide();
                minipallet.show();
                minipallettablelines.empty();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var minitablelines = minipallettablelines.append("<tr><td class='text-left bold'><span class='itemNum'>" + item.ProductID + "</span></br><span class='desc'>" + item.Desc + "</span></td><td><span class='qty'>" + item.Quantity + "</span></td><td class='text-right'><span class='price'>" + item.UnitPrice + "</span></td></tr>");
                    if (i > 0) {
                        minitablelines;
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
}
```

**Problem**
The first and last table rows display undefined in each field. The second and third rows show the proper data. I understand why this is. However, I don't know how to exclude the first and last object from being looped when adding data to the table. I appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any control over the JSON that's being returned? In an ideal world the ItemCount and ItemTotExtPrice would not be in the same array as the items. They should also be key value pairs.

Comment: Your JSON is valid according to syntax, but it is not in correct format . It should be like `{"key":"value"}` pair as @jolyonruss said.

Comment: @jolyonruss Yes, I do have control over the json that is returned by the server. In this case, are you suggesting 3 separate arrays? Is that going to lead to a solution that is more performant than guest271314's below?

Comment: @jolyonruss and @J Santosh are you saying that the value can't be a number, rather it must be a string? My understanding is that it can be either. Please correct me if I'm missing some nuance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `if` condition , `Object.hasOwnProperty()` within `$.each()`

```
if (item.hasOwnProperty("ProductID" || "Desc" || "Quanity" || "UnitPrice")) {
  minipallettablelines
  .append("<tr><td class='text-left bold'><span class='itemNum'>" 
    + item.ProductID + "</span></br><span class='desc'>" 
    + item.Desc + "</span></td><td><span class='qty'>" 
    + item.Quantity + "</span></td><td class='text-right'><span class='price'>" 
    + item.UnitPrice + "</span></td></tr>");
}
```

---

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      "ItemCount":2
   },
   {  
      "ProductID":"4220068",
      "ProdMfg":"",
      "Desc":"Cambridge&#32;AR&#32;Charcoal&#32;Grey",
      "Quantity":1,
      "UnitPrice":"$1.00",
      "ExtPrice":"$1.00"
   },
   {  
      "ProductID":"4220002",
      "ProdMfg":"",
      "Desc":"Cambridge&#32;AR&#32;Dual&#32;Black",
      "Quantity":1,
      "UnitPrice":"$1.00",
      "ExtPrice":"$1.00"
   },
   {  
      "ItemTotExtPrice":2
   }
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  if (item.hasOwnProperty("ProductID" || "Desc" || "Quanity" || "UnitPrice")) {
  console.log(item.ProductID  
    , item.Desc 
    , item.Quantity
    , item.UnitPrice);
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a working solution given the current restraints imposed by the json structure i currently have in place. Thanks for your help!